# Kendo Jquery ForeignKey Dropdownlist values

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

My application is MVC 5, using Kendo UI Jquery editable grid.  One of the column is a dropdownlist using:

```
{ field: "ApplicableCourse_ID", title :"Course", values: myDDL1 }
```

I use the following Ajax to generate the values array **myDDL1**

```
$.ajax({
        url:  '@Url.Action("GetFreeAccessDropdownList", "fff")',
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            myDDL1.push(JSON.stringify(result.Grid1));
           var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.refresh();
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }
    });
```

I get the correct value and text:
[image]

However; the grid show the value instead of the text.  If I use static array:

```
var myDDL1 = [
        { "value": 54, "text": "Fuel Spill Response Plan" },
        { "value": 56, "text": "Community Fuel Contractor Manual" },
        { "value": 91, "text": "Blocking and Cribbing" }];
```

The correct text is displayed.  Is there a difference between dynamic array and static array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the refresh() method of the grid after populating the collection would be insufficient as it would not refresh the templates and the foreign key column.

There are two options:

1. Make the AJAX call directly from the column and there is no need for handing the success callback:

[Remote data binding for foreign key](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.datasource)

2. Set the [autoBind property](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/autobind) of the grid to false. Inside the success callback of your custom AJAX, call the [fetch() method](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/fetch#:%7E:text=Reads%20the%20data%20items%20from,not%20configured%20for%20server%20operations.) of the data source of the grid.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried option 2; didn't work.  Can you explain option 1; unfortunately the link does not explain how to do it.

Comment: Here is an example of the solution - https://dojo.telerik.com/UNuXOBIn. Note that the setTimeout() function of the AJAX request is needed only to make sure that the JS thread has finished initializing the grid and only after that do we call the fetch() method.

Comment: Thank you for your effort

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else has this problem; the solution I used was to generate in the controller a ViewBag of the list:

```
var grid1 = db.Courses.Select(c => new
            {
                value = c.ID,
                text = c.Name,
            }).ToList();
            ViewBag.Course = grid1;
```

In the view

```
var myDDL1 = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Course));
```

The Grid column

```
field: "ApplicableCourse_ID", filterable: { multi: true, search: true }, values: myDDL1
```